# How to set redis databse number to be used in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

In my application and I want all my keys to go to a specific database number.

I checked Redis documentation and found that Redis has 16 databases by default 0-15.

Let's say I want to use database 3.

How can I do it in java spring-boot application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify that in the **application.properties** file like this.

```
spring.redis.database=3
```

after this while creating Jedisconnection factory set this databse to jedisconnectionfactory.

```
    @Autowired
    private RedisProperties redisProperties;


    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {

        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(redisSentinelConfiguration);
        jedisConnectionFactory.setDatabase(this.redisProperties.getDatabase());
        return jedisConnectionFactory;
    }
```

Comment: @prerna What is the use case you are trying to solve by this? Curious to know.

Comment: Actually we want to have app specific keys in redis, we want to have dedicated redis db for that purpose, so that we can flush a specific db without impacting other dbs.